# Applying the same CSS with slight changes to multiple elements

Tags: css, background

I'm currently changing the background image of a div with the following CSS

```
        #portfolio-1 {
        background:
        url(images/portfolio-1.jpg);
        background-size: 100% 100%;
    }
```

This works correctly, however, I have 6 different divs (named portfolio-1,portfolio-2,portfolio-3..) and need to set their background image as well. Is there a more simple way to apply a background image to all of them (with a different file name) without having to do each one individually?

Comment: Do you want all of them to have different backgrounds or the same?

Comment: All different, portfolio-1 will have "image1.jpg", portfolio-2 will have "image2.jpg" etc.

Answer (score 1):

Use CSS variable and you can do this with inline CSS:

```css
.portfolio {
  width:200px;
  height:100px;
  background:var(--img) center/100% 100% no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="portfolio" style="--img:url(https://picsum.photos/200/300?image=0)"></div>
<div class="portfolio" style="--img:url(https://picsum.photos/200/300?image=1069)"></div>
<div class="portfolio" style="--img:url(https://picsum.photos/200/300?image=1050)"></div>
<div class="portfolio" style="--img:url(https://picsum.photos/200/300?image=1048)"></div>
```